# Como fazer Rank() Over() no Apache Ignite

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Estou precisando aplicar algo similar a função Rank() Over() no Apache Ignite. Já pesquisei na documentação e no Github e não me foi retornada qualquer função parecida.

Gostaria de saber quais as soluções que a comunidade vem aplicando para este tipo de situação, quando a encontram.

Documentação da Função Rank Over:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Lembrando, preciso aplicar este função no Apache Ignite, e desta maneira do link acima não funciona.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.